# Add a user who already exist in salesforce to your app

Tags: permissions, tasks, app, user

I have created an app. Now would like to add users to my app. However on ethe users that I would like to add is already a salesforce developer user. So I cannot create a new user using his email.
gives error:

Duplicate Username.
Another user has already selected this username.

Since the user already exist in salesforce.

So how can I look him up and assign permission to him?
(in my app I wanna assign a task to him)

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce usernames are unique throughout Salesforce, so you actually can't add this user as-is. You can get around it by assigning that username to something different than their actual email address. For example, you could try first.last@myapp.com as their username while leaving their email alone.

There are some ways to get around this requirement at the login level, which is what Greenstork was probably referring to in the comment, but these would take additional development.